# Outerglow Image issue in android button background

Tags: android, button

I am creating one application , in that application i used background for button . Background image has outer glow, so when i set that image to button background it shows me black color instead of outer glow image .

How can resolve this issue ? Please help me to solve this.

Here i add two images .

1) Image in which i got problem of outer glow.
2) Actual image used in button background.

[image: Problem Image]

[image: Actual Image]

Comment: are you using two images ?

Comment: @CapDroid can you explain me in details ?

Answer (score 0):

heres a link that explains different button presses  a good clear explanation

http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/AnimalSounds.html